# Singletons and memory management in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, singleton, static-members

I have a singleton as class method:

```
+(WordsModel *) defaultModel{
    static WordsModel *model = nil;  

    if (!model) {
        model =  [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    return model;
}
```

What happens with the static reference to model inside the method? Will it ever get released?

Comment: It does look as if it will get released in the next run cycle of your app, as the reference to your WordsModel is not retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work as you are autoreleasing your instance of your class...

On the next runloop, it will be released...

Take a look at the standard singleton patterns:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern

The static instance should be a global variable, that will be freed when your app exits...

Comment: Whether it should be a global variable or not is debatable. By limiting its scope to the method, one enforces the use of that method to access it. Instance methods don't need a global, because they already have `self`, and class methods that need access to a particular instance should arguably be instance methods.

Answer (score 3):

Not only will it get released (because you sent it an `-autorelease` message), your next attempt to use it will probably lead to a crash because the `model` pointer wasn't set to nil when the object was released. So, it will then point to memory that's either garbage, or (if that memory has been re-used) to a different object than the one you expected.